# Get carat position on focus for an input lement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the current cursor position when a user clicks inside a filled input box. But using `this.selectionStart;` only gives '0' using the following code:

```
$('.exampleDiv').on('focus', 'input', function() {
        console.log(this.selectionStart);
});
```

Html

```
<div class="exampleDiv" style="width=300px;"><input value="This is a prefilled value"></div>
```

My guess is that it gives the value 0 because the `.on(focus)` code runs before the cursor position is set in the input box.

Is there any other event for input element activation which can be used?

Example: Input box has value: "This is a prefilled value"

User clicks on "pre|filled" so I want to get the number of characters after which the cursor appears. Is there a way to get this?

Comment: Please provide us with html and css to help you with your problem

Comment: change the event to on 'click'

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct. However, your `this` context in the event listener is not your input element. I recommend either saving the reference to the element in a variable (if you know the ID beforehand) or accessing the element through `event.target` (you'd also have to add the `event` parameter to your event listener in that case).

A very basic working example (check your console for output or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6t414qkf/1/)):

```js
var input = document.getElementById('foo');

function caretController() {
  var caretPos = input.selectionStart;

  console.log('caret position:', caretPos);
}

input.addEventListener('focus', caretController);
```

```html
<input id="foo" type="text">
```

And with `event.target`:

```js
function caretController(event) {
  var caretPos = event.target.selectionStart;

  console.log('caret position:', caretPos);
}

document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].addEventListener('focus', caretController);
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Carat position is coming out to be 0 with your answer. I checked by copying your code in my script and "Run code snippet"

Comment: Are you sure? I've tested it on my own computer (Chrome & Firefox) and asked a friend to test it (FF & Safari) and there were no issues. Could you create a jsfiddle with the code that is failing for you?